# Emacs' Magit requred feature 'isearch' was not provided

Tags: git, emacs, magit

After upgrading packages in Emacs configuration Magit stopped working for me.

```lisp
(require 'magit)
```

Fails with an error `error "Required feature ‘isearch’ was not provided"`.

This is whole stack trace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Required feature ‘isearch’ was not provided")
  require(isearch)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-496672> nil "/home/marek/Dotfiles/emacs.d/.cask/25.3/elpa/transient-20190504.1155/transient.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 2066
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/marek/Dotfiles/emacs.d/.cask/25.3/elpa/transient-20190504.1155/transient.el" "/home/marek/Dotfiles/emacs.d/.cask/25.3/elpa/transient-20190504.1155/transient.el" nil t)
  require(transient)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-724674> nil "/home/marek/Dotfiles/emacs.d/.cask/25.3/elpa/magit-20190504.1425/magit-mode.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1313
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/marek/Dotfiles/emacs.d/.cask/25.3/elpa/magit-20190504.1425/magit-mode.el" "/home/marek/Dotfiles/emacs.d/.cask/25.3/elpa/magit-20190504.1425/magit-mode.el" nil t)
  require(magit-mode)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-170353> nil "/home/marek/Dotfiles/emacs.d/.cask/25.3/elpa/magit-20190504.1425/magit-core.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1353
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/marek/Dotfiles/emacs.d/.cask/25.3/elpa/magit-20190504.1425/magit-core.el" "/home/marek/Dotfiles/emacs.d/.cask/25.3/elpa/magit-20190504.1425/magit-core.el" nil t)
  require(magit-core)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/marek/Dotfiles/emacs.d/.cask/25.3/elpa/magit-20190504.1425/magit.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 2120
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/marek/Dotfiles/emacs.d/.cask/25.3/elpa/magit-20190504.1425/magit.el" "/home/marek/Dotfiles/emacs.d/.cask/25.3/elpa/magit-20190504.1425/magit.el" nil t)
  require(magit)
  eval((require (quote magit)) nil)
  elisp--eval-last-sexp(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil)
  #<subr call-interactively>(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  apply(#<subr call-interactively> eval-last-sexp (nil nil))
  call-interactively@ido-cr+-record-current-command(#<subr call-interactively> eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  apply(call-interactively@ido-cr+-record-current-command #<subr call-interactively> (eval-last-sexp nil nil))
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-last-sexp)
```

~For now, I had to remove Magit from my configuration which solved the issue.~

For now I hacked it by adding

```
(provide 'isearch)
```

on top of my initialization

I thought I might first ask here before creating bug report.

Comment: If you try this in an `emacs -Q` session do you get the same issue? `isearch` is a core part of Emacs. It should be available out of the box.

Comment: `isearch.el` in Emacs 25.3 does not `(provide 'isearch)`.  Are you sure the version of Magit you're using is compatible with Emacs 25?  That `transient` stuff is very new / not yet in a stable release. (Edit: It does indicate 25.1 as a minimum, so yeah -- raise a Magit bug report.)

Comment: @chris I tried to clone Magit and run only master git against my emacs version and the problem was there still.

Comment: @philis Thanks for validating it. My Emacs-fu is not as I would like it to be. I'm going to raise an issue in Magit Github.

Comment: for the record, this has been already fixed so we can probably expect this to be fixed in next release https://github.com/magit/transient/commit/17ad01e0c724aa07d77a27836ea5a38f1a9882e0